# Dependency issue installing Asterisk 1.8 on Amazon Linux Server

Tags: amazon-web-services, yum, rpm, asterisk, dependencies

I'm trying to install Asterisk 1.8 on an Amazon Linux Server (2015.09).

```
sudo yum install asterisk
```

This results in the following errors:

```
Error: Package: libresample-0.1.3-12.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libsndfile.so.1(libsndfile.so.1.0)(64bit)
Error: Package: asterisk-1.8.32.3-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libgsm.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: libresample-0.1.3-12.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libsndfile.so.1()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I tried `rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest`, and then yum again, but that didn't fix it.

So it seems I need `libsndfile.so.1` and `libgsm.so.1`.

**How do I install or fix this, and how can I get Asterisk installed?**

Comment: I'd recommend using a different linux distro - Amazon linux is poorly-supported, poorly-understood, and behaves in unpredictable ways. CentOS or Debian would be a better starting place.

Comment: EPEL is not compatible with Amazon Linux. So I don't know what you're trying to do, but it's not going to work. Get rid of Amazon Linux and try again with a more reasonable distro.

Comment: My advice is to switch distro. Centos is available and offers those packages differently than Amazon Linux

Comment: Thanks mate but this is not a competition, not at all :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the rpm packages that contain the missing libraries. The problem is those packages are not present in the repositories you are using.

You can use [rpmfind](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php) to find which packages provide your libraries and in which repositories you might find them.